# Vuejs template inheritance

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

How can I use template inheritance (Like what jade has, `extends file.jade` and then the blocks with the same name would be overwritten)?

I know that I can do everything with composition, but for components like footer and header which appear on every single page except one or two (e.g.login page) I must write them on every single component. In my app I have a two level navigation and it seems painful to repeat them on every one of those child components :(

I know that I can use jade and then inherit a jade file within my components, but it seems wrong because I would have some jade and some Vue files, is there any other way to do this?

```
// Component.vue

<template lang="jade">
  extends ./StandardLayout
  block content
  router-view
</template>
```

```
// StandardLayout.Vue

<template lang="jade">
  div
    navbar
    div.container
      div.spacer
      div.row
        block content
<template>
```

What I've settled for, is a layouts folder filled with jade layouts and I use them to extend my components. I used vue-cli with [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if you are using a `router-view` you should just be dynamically changing out that one element with new page content. So, you only need the layout code for one page.

Comment: No you are not, Im using the router but there are some parts that are just html markup that I dont want to inherit them using the router, I just want the markup inherited, Im using the router method now but it seems like overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **most general** case if you have to repeat the same HTML over and over, one option you could use is `<partial>`s.

```
<partial name="header"></partial>
<div>My content content</div>
<partial name="footer"></partial>
```

Where you declare partials as

```
Vue.partial('header', '<h3>This is the title: {{title}}</h3>')
Vue.partial('footer', '<footer>Mini footer</footer>')
```

However if you are building a **Single Page Application** the strategy you could follow is to simply have a header and a footer around your `<router-view>`, here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates how to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/vdqutw2y/

```
<header><h1>
My title: {{title}}
</h1></header>
<p>
  <a v-link="{ path: '/foo' }">Go to Foo</a>
  <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Go to Bar</a>
</p>
<router-view></router-view>
<footer>Such footer, many links, wow!</footer>
```

Comment: Well I used router view as u suggested, I was looking for a way to DRY html markup :) is it wrong to use stupid (just html markup, without any js) components? it seemed a little silly to me

Comment: What I wrote is a proof of concept. If you are developing a large application, of course you want to encapsulate complex HTML in components.

Comment: by the way, partials no longer exist as of Vue 2.0

Answer (score -2):

If you know Chinses, please look [it](https://miser.github.io/2018/11/17/vue-component-extends/)

```
// Base Component
<template>
  <div class="base-thing special-class">
    <Button />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from './ButtonClick'
export default {
  components: { Button }
}
</script>

// Inheriting Component
<script>
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent'
import Button from './OtherButton'

export default {
  extends: BaseComponent
  components: {
    Button
  }
} 
</script>
```

The Button of Child Component will be replaced OtherButton. We can do something in the OtherButton